# which input lost the focus and get the value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have the inputs like this

```
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker0" value="12"></b></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker1" value="322"></b></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker2" value="25"></b></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker3" value="332"></b></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker4" value="23"></b></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker5" value="344"></b></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker6" value="34"></b></td>
```

I want to get the value of the input that was clicked. using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For which one lost focus, you could use `blur` to get `input` id and value:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    alert("input id: " + $(this).attr("id") + " value: " + $(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmARC/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

should do it